# Generic object pool

Tags: c#, object-pooling

Is it possible to create a generic object pool that creates new objects inside it?
Plus it would be nice if this object creation could receive parameters.

```
    public interface IPoolable
    {
        void Dispose();
    }


    public class ObjectPool<T> where T : IPoolable
    {
        private List<T> pool;

        public T Get()
        {
            if(pool.count > 0)
            {
                return pool.Pop();
            }
            else
            {
                return new T(); //  <- How to do this properly?
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass : IPoolable
    {
        int id;

        public SomeClass(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }

    public class OtherClass : IPoolable
    {
        string name;
        int id;

        public OtherClass(string name, int id)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }
```

In a way that it can be used like this if it could receive parameters.

```
SomeClass a = myPool.Get(2);
OtherClass b = myOtherPool.Get("foo", 4);
```

Or this would also be fine if parameters were not possible.

```
SomeClass a = myPool.Get();
a.id = 2;
OtherClass b = myOtherPool.Get();
b.name = "foo";
b.id = 4;
```

Comment: Are you basically talking about a factory? It's a common OO pattern. The pooling could be a component of it, but, in general, instantiating an object is extremely quick and pooling would be unnecessary unless there's a lot of object setup to be done in the constructor. The only way to make it generic really would be to use reflection to instantiate the objects.

Comment: He is talking about maintaining a pool of already created objects and only creating a new instance if the pool is empty, kind of like how connection pooling works only generic instead of just connections. I agree though, for light objects it is a bit of a waste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Activator.CreateInstance` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static object CreateInstance(
    Type type,
    params object[] args
)
```

Like this

```
return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), id);
```

There is, however, no way to specify that a type must provide a constructor with an argument; neither in an interface declaration, nor in the generic type constraints, nor with class inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for something similar and came across this:

```
public class ObjectPool<TObject>
    {
        private int maxPoolSize;
        private SpinLock poolLock;
        private Dictionary<Type, Stack<TObject>> poolCache;
        private Func<TObject> factory;

        public ObjectPool(int poolSize)
        {
            this.maxPoolSize = poolSize;
            this.poolLock = new SpinLock(false);
            this.poolCache = new Dictionary<Type, Stack<TObject>>();
        }

        public ObjectPool(int poolSize, Func<TObject> factory) : this(poolSize)
        {
            this.factory = factory;
        }

        public T Rent<T>() where T : TObject
            => (T)this.Rent(typeof(T));

        public TObject Rent(Type type)
        {
            bool lockTaken = false;
            Stack<TObject> cachedCollection;
            this.poolLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);

            try
            {
                if (!this.poolCache.TryGetValue(type, out cachedCollection))
                {
                    cachedCollection = new Stack<TObject>();
                    this.poolCache.Add(type, cachedCollection);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (lockTaken)
                {
                    this.poolLock.Exit(false);
                }
            }

            if (cachedCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                TObject instance = cachedCollection.Pop();
                if (instance != null)
                    return instance;
            }

            // New instances don't need to be prepared for re-use, so we just return it.
            if (this.factory == null)
            {
                return (TObject)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.factory();
            }
        }

        public void Return(TObject instanceObject)
        {
            Stack<TObject> cachedCollection = null;
            Type type = typeof(TObject);

            bool lockTaken = false;
            this.poolLock.Enter(ref lockTaken);
            try
            {
                if (!this.poolCache.TryGetValue(type, out cachedCollection))
                {
                    cachedCollection = new Stack<TObject>();
                    this.poolCache.Add(type, cachedCollection);
                }

                if (cachedCollection.Count >= this.maxPoolSize)
                {
                    return;
                }

                cachedCollection.Push(instanceObject);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (lockTaken)
                {
                    this.poolLock.Exit(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's a very nice implementation that I shamelessly stole from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14008)

It supports pooling of any objects that inherit from the generic type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
public class ObjectPool<T>
{
    private Queue<T> _pool = new Queue<T>();

    private const int _maxObjects = 100;  // Set this to whatever

    public T Get(params object[] parameters)
    {
        T obj;

        if (_pool.Count < 1)
            obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), parameters);
        else
            obj = _pool.Dequeue();

        return obj;
    }

    public void Put(T obj)
    {
        if (_pool.Count < _maxObjects)
            _pool.Enqueue(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: That will do. Thanks!